# Rails: Cache where queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to cache some DB-queries as the values inside the DB didn't get changed often (once a month or so).

Unfortunately my rails app runs very very slow as the DB contains 500+ products. I know that there is some kind of cache available but I'm not sure how to cache queries like this:

```
<% Group.all.each do |p| %>
 <%= f.collection_select(:product, Warehouse.where(category: p.name1), :product, :product, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
<% end %>
```

I have the dalli gem and memcached installed.

Sorry for the noob question. I'm pretty new to rails. I found this [article](http://codebeerstartups.com/2014/11/scaling-ruby-on-rails-by-caching-your-database-queries/) but don't now how to adapt. Maybe one of you does :/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is not answer to your question, but 500 products (i.e. perhaps a few thousand related records in the db) is not a big deal for modern databases and your app should not be slow due to this amount of data. Are you sure you have an index properly defined for the where queries? E.g. an index for the category name on the `warehouses` table? That should speed up the queries in the first place.

Comment: Hi @BoraMa I'm actually not familiar with that but yes - I was wondering if 500 products really could slow down the DB (running on SSD w/ 4 Cores and 32 GB RAM). Where and what should I define to add an index? A new migration or in the controller?

Comment: Aren't you doing a N+1 query ?

Comment: Could be. Inside my views all products are getting printed with their specific category. My Warehouse table (with products) have a category-column as well as my Category table where the categories are defined. How can I avoid N+1 queries?

Comment: How many groups do you have?

Comment: 30 Categories (Group table).

Comment: There should be a relationship between your group and production table.
You should exploit to load all objects and their association at once:
Group.includes(:products).each do |group|
   f.collection_select(:group, group.products, .....)
end